# KeyCloack Settings behind Azure WAG (Web Application Gateway)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, keycloak

We have a corporative KeyCloak server which sits on Azure Account “A”.

We are now developing an ASP.Net Core Application that is on Azure Account “B”. This application is behind an Azure WAG.

The users access the application from the internet through the WAG and hits the Azure WebApp:
**"https://myexternaldomain.com"** => **"https://myinternalazuredomain.azuresites.net"**.

As expected the users is redirected to Keycloak corporate server (**"https://sso.corporate.com"**). Once the user is logged in, he is being redirected to the callback address **"https://myexternaldomain.com/oauth/callback"**.

At this moment we get a exception **“Correlation Failed”**, **“Unknown Location”**.

Architecture and Exception below:
[Architecture and Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhgUy.png)

We believe that the problem is related to the address the users is using (**"https://myexternaldomain.com"**) being different from the actual address the server is on (**"https://myinternalazuredomain.azuresites.net"**). And this makes even more sense when we take into account that it was working fine before the addition of the WAG.

Can you guys give us some insight?

Thanks

Best Regards

Take Care

Comment: Please, add the exception text as a text to the question, your image is unreadable. It also unclear what code raised that exception.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple things that needed to be done to get KeyCloak + AppService to work in this scenario.

We had to add the same Certs to Wag and AppService, so KeyCloak would understand it as the same request.

Also the network team misconfigured the WAG, and some of the headers were not being forwarded, and KeyCloak would not accept the given Auth Token as valid for the current request.